# Need help extracting date, month, and year from this date format

Tags: javascript, date

I need help converting this date format.
Here are the date string I receive from a server, it can be `M/DD/YYYY` or `M/D/YYYY` or `MM/D/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`.

EDIT: Sorry, my bad. After the format above, there is additional string of time `HH:MM:SS AM` so the complete string I receive will be `M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM`

My problem now is I use String.substring(x, y) to extract the date, month, and year.

So far I only managed to determine the location of "/" but I'm still thinking how to use it in the substring method.

```
var separators = [];
for(var b = 0, c = String.length; b < c; b++){
    if(String[b] === '/'){
        separators.push(b);
    }
}
```

I'm confused how to extract the date and month dynamically and then pad "0" in front of the single digit number, so I appreciate any helps. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use split function in string  dateString.split("/");

Comment: I [updated my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511575/601179) according to your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dt = "10/6/2012 12:34:56 AM".split(' '); 
dt = dt[0].split('/'); 

// dt[0] => month
// dt[1] => day
// dt[2] => year
```

it works with any of the above format - `M/DD/YYYY` or `M/D/YYYY` or `MM/D/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` - (and it's easier than using substring)

then to add a pad to month and day just use `slice()` like so

```
dt[0] = ("0"+ dt[0]).slice(-2);
dt[1] = ("0"+ dt[1]).slice(-2);
```

and to get a padded data just re-join the array parts

```
dt = dt.join('/');
```

Example jsbin : http://jsbin.com/exodos/2/edit

Comment: Sorry, I missed some info in the question. Thanks for informing me the use of `split`, but it seems it can't work with the String I updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date= '1/3/2012'//your date string
,dateArray = date.split("/");
for(var k =0; k < 2; k++){
 if((dateArray[k] + "").length ==1){
      dateArray[k] = "0"+dateArray[k];
 }
}
var newDate= dateArray.join("/");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znfQF/)

Comment: That's a lot of code to do such a simple task, don't you think?

Comment: yes, But I just provided a alternate options and code is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can do the job. The following doesn't care whether it's a date as m/d/y or y/d/m/ or whatever, it just pads single digit numbers with a leading zero. It only works with integers, it will not behave well with decimal seconds.

```
function fixDate(d) {
  var re = /\d+/g;
  return d.replace(re, function(s) {
    return (s < 10? '0' : '') + +s;
  });
}

fixDate('2/3/2012 3:5:3 am'); // 02/03/2012 03:05:03 am
```